# How to send a break statement from a function to a while loop?

Tags: python, while-loop, exit, break

I am trying to repeatedly ask the user to enter a string. If that string is "bye", the program should return "Bye" and terminate.

I can't figure out how to have the decide function tell the while loop that it's time to terminate.

```
def decide(greeting):
    if greeting == "hi":
        return "Hello"
    elif greeting == "bye":
        return "Bye"

x = input("Insert here: ")
while True:
    print(decide(x))
    x = input("Insert here: ")
```

EDIT: People in the comments are saying to use a conditional in the while loop for checking the returned value. I cannot do that because in reality the returned value `"Bye"` is stored in a local variable. Those two functions are inside a class in reality and I'd prefer to keep the while loop short on conditionals.

Comment: Why can't you check the returned string in while loop to exit?

Comment: Like @Krishna said, do a `if` inside `while` to check for the returned value and `break` accordingly.

Comment: @Krishna please see my edits.

Comment: What about the answer suggested by @Viktor Petrov. Is that doable? Or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can do your printing in your function and check its output in the while loop:

```
def decide(greeting):
    if greeting == "bye":
        print("Bye")
        return False  # only break on "bye";
    elif greeting == "hi":
        print("Hello")
    return True

while True:
    x = input("Insert here: ")
    if not decide(x):
        break
```

**EDIT** based on clarified question (no printing inside your function). Your function can have more than one output, for example:

```
def decide(greeting):
    if greeting == "bye":
        return "Bye", False  # return reply and status;
    elif greeting == "hi":
        return "Hello", True
    else:
        return greeting, True  # default case;

while True:
    x = input("Insert here: ")
    reply, status = decide(x)
    print(reply)
    if not status:
        break
```

Comment: The decode function is in reality inside a class. And the final output will be JSON strings containing those Hellos and Byes. Therefore, having print() functions inside the class doesn't do any good. I just want to feed the function with a string and have that function **return** something depending on that string.

Comment: That's a big piece of the puzzle you left out in your initial question, might have been worth including your actual class code, since there might be a more elegant solution to your issue. I've updated my answer so that the decide function returns the value of the reply string and a status boolean, which you can use to determine if you should break the loop. The alternative is to go with what @Krishna has suggested and just have another if statement in your while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
def decide(greeting):
    if greeting == "hi":
         return "Hello"
    elif greeting == "bye":
        return "Bye"

x = input("Insert here: ")

while True:
    n = (decide(x))
    print(n)

    if(n == "Bye"):
        break

    x = input("Insert here: ")
```